# Unexpected output of typeof in the example

Tags: javascript, typeof

In the following example, I am trying to get output adding a number to typeof a function, but output seems different.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script>

var k = 1;
if (1) {
   eval(function foo(){});
   k += typeof foo; 
}
console.log(k); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1function
```

**Actual Output:**

```
1undefined
```

Can someone explain why the output is different than expected?

> **Note: type of eval(function(){}) gives result of function.**

[image]

Comment: The name of a function expression is only visible inside that function expression.

Comment: @Xufox: can u explain more?

Comment: More what? There isn’t really anything more to explain. `function foo(){}` is a function expression (in expression context inside `eval`’s parameters). Its name `foo` is not accessible outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t actually need that `eval` for this snippet. `typeof (function foo(){})` vs. `typeof foo` has the same result. You don’t need `eval` because `eval(function foo(){})` and `(function foo(){})` are identical, since the argument is not a string. If you want to use `eval`, use strings instead:

```js
var x = function foo(){};

console.log(eval(x) === x); // true, because they’re identical

eval("function foo(){}");
// or
eval("var foo = function foo(){}");

console.log(foo); // function foo, because one of the above `eval`s declared it
```

`function foo(){}`, here, is a function expression. Their names are only accessible inside themselves, not outside. A function declaration or an assigned function expression *would* be accessible outside.

```js
(function foo(){}); // (…) forces expression context. `foo` is not defined outside of it.

console.log(foo); // ReferenceError
```

```js
var foo = function foo(){}; // Right-hand side is an expression, thus this is a function expression, but its result is assigned to a variable.

console.log(foo); // function foo
```

```js
var bar = function foo(){}; // Same thing, but with a different variable.

console.log(bar); // function foo
console.log(foo); // ReferenceError, since the name `foo` still is not visible outside.
```

```js
function foo(){} // Statement context, thus this is a function declaration

console.log(foo); // function foo
```

So `(function foo(){ console.log(foo); })` would be fine, if the function was called, not necessarily with the same name.

Finally, `typeof` returns `"undefined"` for undeclared variables.

Answer (score -1):

typeof foo returns undefined because it is not defined in that scope

k +=undefined is casted to a string and results in:

1function

Comment: That I know. Explain why not casted?

Comment: @Deadpool What do you expect to be casted that isn’t casted…?

Comment: function foo(){} is just not visible because it is declared inside  eval()

Answer (score -1):

eval() expects a **string** as argument.
so you have to wrap **function foo()** inside quotes.

```
var k = 1;

if (1) {
  eval('function foo(){}');
  k += typeof foo; 
}

console.log(k);
```

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Try this code in a javascript console, you'll get the desired outcome.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, what you have done is giving a name to that function, but you didn't "tied" it to a variable, so the function exists, but there's no "pointer" pointing to that function. `typeof` needs a "pointer" to something to evaluate, but you didn't declare anyone, you just gave a name to that function. That's useful for debugging purposes only if you won't plan to execute the function directly.

It's ok to pass the object directly too:

```
var k = 1;
if (1) {
   k += typeof function foo(){}; //1function
}
console.log(k);
```

Comment: Please, dont change question or code. Explain in that only.

Comment: @Deadpool I already explained it to you. Giving names to functions in contexts where I don't plan to call them by their name is something I usually do to make things easier for me when it comes to debugging time.

Comment: @Deadpool Yes, after testing that it doesn't matter if it's `eval` or any other function. Try to declare another one by yourself and do the same opperation. You will find it's the same case.